# Xpath Получить текст между HTML тегами

Tags: html, python, xpath

Есть `html` со следующей структурой

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Headerh1</h1>
    Text1 <br/> after header1 
  <h3>Headerh3.1</h3> 
    Text2 <br/> after header3.1 
  <h3>Headerh3.2</h3>
    Text3 <br/> after header3.2 
  <h3>Headerh3.3</h3>
    Text4 <br/> after header3.3 
 </div>
```

Как получить текст `Text1 after header1`?

`div[@class='text']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=1]` - возвращает текст после всех тегов.

Найден вариант `//div[@class='text']/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::text()`, хотелось бы более гибкое решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структура постоянная и, как вы отметили, `<br/> может встречаться сколько угодно раз`, попробуйте получать текст после `h1` и до `h3`, как результат комбинации двух запросов

```
//div[@class='text']/h1/following-sibling::text()[1]
//div[@class='text']/h3/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

Или объединить (вдруг текст будет между `<br>`)

```
//div[@class='text']/h1/following-sibling::text()[not(preceding-sibling::h3)]
```

Comment: Вот не знаю как их подружить

Comment: @dMazay подружено

Answer (score 0):

Первая строка "Text1"

```
//div[@class='text']/h1/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Вторая строка "after header1"

```
//div[@class='text']/h1/following-sibling::text()[2]
```

После этого сделайте конкатенацию строк.

Либо, что-то подобное:

```
//text()[preceding::*[contains(text(),'Headerh1')] and following::*[contains(text(),'Headerh3.1')] and not(contains(., 'Term:'))]
```

Comment: <br/> может встречаться сколько угодно раз